# Cannot get an img element that is dynamically added to a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, mutation-observers

Let's say I am trying to run code bellow on 9gag to get images that are dynamically added form infinite scroll. I am trying to figure out how to get img element.

```
    //want to do something useful in this function
    checkIfImg = function(toCheck){
        if (toCheck.is('img')) {
            console.log("finaly");
        }
        else {
            backImg = toCheck.css('background-image');
            if (backImg != 'none'){
            console.log("background fynaly");
            }
        }
    }
    //that works just fine, since it is not for dynamic content
    //$('*').each(function(){ 
    //    checkIfImg($(this));
    //})

    //this is sums up all my attempts
        var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
                switch (mutation.type) {
                case 'childList':
                    Array.prototype.forEach.call(mutation.target.children, function (child) {
                         if ( child.tagName === "IMG" ) {
                             console.log("img");
                         }
                        child.addEventListener( 'load', checkIfImg, false );
                        console.log("forEachChild");
                        console.log(child);
                        checkIfImg($(child));
                        $(child).each(function(){ 
                            console.log("inside each");
                            console.log($(this));
                            if ($(this).tagName == "IMG"){
                                console.log("img");
                            }
                            checkIfImg($(this));
                        })
                    });

                    break;
                default:
                }
            });
        });
    observer.observe(document, {childList: true, subtree: true});
```

Observer gets lots of different elements but I can't seem to find any img among them.

Comment: Are the `img` direct children of the inserted nodes? Have you tried `mutation.target.querySelectorAll('img')`?

Comment: @msg That works thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for `img` elements deeper down the tree, not only the direct children of `mutation.children` (each of them may contain additional children).

You could do this with a `$.find('img')`, and use an array to eliminate duplicates:

```
let imageList = [];

//want to do something useful in this function
function checkIfImg(toCheck) {
  // find all images in changed node
  let images = toCheck.find('img');
  for(let image of images) {
    let imageSource = $(image).attr('src');
    if(!imageList.includes(imageSource)) {
      imageList.push(imageSource);
      console.log("image:", imageSource);
    }
  }
};

// get existing images
checkIfImg($(document));

// observe changes
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(mutation => checkIfImg($(mutation.target)));
});
observer.observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Comment: that works as I wanted too! Thank you! How would you include css check for background img : ```toCheck.css('background-image')```, the same as you did ```.find``` on a node?

Comment: instead of `$(image).attr('src');` you can use `$(image).css('background-image');` if you want to get the background-image value, although `img` tags typically don't have a backgroundImage

Comment: Thank you for your help.